# Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, undefined

I am completely new to Backbone JS. I thought I could solve this minor problem by myself but I can't figure why I am still getting this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined

when trying to extend a Backbone.Model. `backbone.js` is called before the script that uses it so I don't get it.

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/backbone.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

### My external file main.js

```
(function($) {
    window.Doc = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults : {
            id : '???',
            title : 'Le titre de mon modèle',
            text : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer varius ipsum nec porta dignissim. Donec a elementum magna. Donec sagittis magna eu nulla ullamcorper dictum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam volutpat felis vehicula, congue mi at, lobortis dolor.',
            keywords : 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
        },
        initialize : function Doc() {
            console.log('Doc Constructor');
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I also get the following error coming from backbone.js:219

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'each' of undefined

Comment: Are you sure your backbone.js file is in the correct place and loaded?

Comment: Thanks for reply! Surely, it is correctly loaded with a `304 Not Modified` status.

Comment: Backbone is dependent on Underscore, and you may need json2 as well. See http://backbonejs.org/

Comment: I indeed forgot to load `underscore.js`. It works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You forgot to import `underscore.js`.
It is a Backbone requirement.

[Grab it here!](http://underscorejs.org/)

Comment: Many thanks for pointing out that `underscore.js` was missing. All works great now!

Comment: The order of references is important as well: underscore.js needs to be referenced before backbone.js in your script tags.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue while running jasmine testcases using SpecRunner.html, so when specifying backbone.js in your dependencies in SpecRunner.html, add jquery and underscore.js first, because backbone depends on them.

Comment: You truly nailed hard to catch thing that underscore.js should be included before backbone.js